# How to use JSP to get cookie value correctly? Reading a cookie with an '=' in the value is truncated

Tags: jsp, cookies

I use IE developer tools to check cookies:

```
IE 11 >> Press F12 >> Network >> Details >> Cookies
```

it shows my cookie key/value properly:

```
Key: SSO
Value: AP_KEY=11111&SSO_KEY=22222&ACCOUNT=JOHN_SMITH
```

But when I use jsp to get cookie value I always get "AP_KEY".
Here is my code:

```
    Cookie cookies [] = request.getCookies();
    Cookie myCookie = null;
    if (cookies != null){
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {              
            out.println("Name: " + cookies [i].getName());
            out.println("Value: " + cookies [i].getValue());                
        }
    }
```

result is:

```
Name: SSO Value: AP_KEY
```

I add encode but still get "AP_KEY":

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode(cookies [i].getValue(), "UTF-8");
```

Any comments and suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My web server is Tomcat 7. After a lot of searching, I found this post:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49252

this post mention that there is a configuration option to allow equal signs in a cookie value, since 6.0.24, see
        http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/systemprops.html

according the document, I add

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_EQUALS_IN_VALUE=true"
```

in catalina.sh, and problem resolved!